# jQuery.each and variable scope

Tags: jquery

```
$grid.find( 'div.bb-bookblock' ).each( function( i ) 
{                               
    var $bookBlock = $(this),
        $nav = $bookBlock.next(),
        $navNext = $nav.find('.bb-nav-next'),
        $navPrev = $nav.find('.bb-nav-prev'),
        $navFirst = $nav.find('.bb-nav-first'),
        $navLast = $nav.find('.bb-nav-last'),
        $playStop =  $nav.find('.bb-nav-play-stop'),
        isPlaying = false,
        autoplayTimer = null,
        bb = $bookBlock.bookblock( 
        {
            speed : 600,
            shadows : false
        });

});
```

will all the variables inside the .each function have scope only inside the loop? For example autoPlayTimer will be the result of setInterval. I want to make sure I am not overwriting variables. It seems it is working ok, but I want to make sure I understand `$().each`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables in Javascript  have `functional scope.`

So all the variables declared inside locally will only be available in the scope of `$.each`  `because of the callback that is a function`.

```
$grid.find('div.bb-bookblock').each(function (i) {
    var $bookBlock = $(this),
        $nav = $bookBlock.next(),
        autoplayTimer = null;

    bb = $bookBlock.bookblock({
        speed: 600,
        shadows: false
    });
    console.log($bookblock) // logs the current jQuery object in iteration
    console.log($nav) // logs the next element
    console.log(autoplayTimer) // null or the value if available
});

console.log($bookblock) // undefined
console.log($nav) // undefined
console.log(autoplayTimer) // undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

Variables defined in functions are always in scope of this function only. This is not a matter of each() but of the `function(i) {...}`.